# Definite Integral, use a power series.

Tags: definite-integrals, power-series

Use a power series to approximate the definite integral, I, to six decimal places.

I tried to definite integral, but the answer is wrong. Where did I make a mistake?

$$\int_{0}^{0.2} \ln(1+x^4)\ dx = \int_{0}^{0.2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^{n+1}\cdot x^{4n}}{n(4n+1)}\ dx
= \left[\frac {x^5}{5} - \frac {x^9}{18} +\frac {x^{13}}{39} - \frac {x^{17}}{68} ... \right]\bigg|_{0}^{0.2} $$

I used the first 3 terms, the error is at most $$\frac {0.2^{17}}{68} $$

So,  $$I \approx 0.000060 $$

The answer is wrong! How do I figure it out? Thank you.

Comment: You need to put exponents in braces if they're more than one character.

Comment: I get $I\approx 0.00006397$ from the first three terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. One may use the Taylor series expansion
$$
\log (1+u)=u-\frac{u^2}2+\frac{u^3}3-\frac{u^4}4+\frac{u^5}5+\cdots, \quad |u|<1,
$$ giving, for $0<a<1$,
$$
\int_0^a\log (1+x^4)\:dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\int_0^a\frac{x^{4n}}n\:dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{a^{4n+1}}{n(4n+1)}.
$$ Then, for $0<a<1$, using the classic inequality (for alternating series)
$$
\left|\sum_{n=n_0}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{a^{4n+1}}{n(4n+1)}\right|\leq \frac{a^{4n_0+1}}{n_0(4n_0+1)}, \quad n_0\geq1,
$$ you get
$$
\left|\int_0^a\log (1+x^4)\:dx-\sum_{n=1}^{n_0}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{a^{4n}}{n(4n+1)}\right|\leq\frac{a^{4n_0+1}}{n_0(4n_0+1)}.
$$ By applying it to $a=0.2$ and $n_0=2$, we obtain
$$
\left|\int_0^{0.2}\log (1+x^4)\:dx-\sum_{n=1}^2(-1)^{n-1}\frac{(0.2)^{4n}}{n(4n+1)}\right|\leq\frac{(0.2)^9}{2\times9}\approx 0.00000003.
$$

Answer (score 2):

The first two terms are $(0.2)^5/5 = 0.000064$ and $-1\cdot(0.2)^9/18 \approx -0.00000002844,$ so the error is in calculating your first term.

Adding up the four terms you have in your question agrees with Wolfram's exact answer:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+ln(1%2Bx%5E4)+dx+from+0+to+0.2

So your terms are correct.  You just evaluated them incorrectly.