# Is this possible? Integrating a power series...

Tags: calculus, power-series

### Work

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-x^2}\, dx = \frac{\sqrt \pi}{2}$$
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \sum_\limits{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k(x^{2k})}{k!}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}2$$

I don't know much about this I just thought hey right we have the function what if we wrote it as the power series and integrated that and got the sum would it work? On a limb I saw this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1688967/definite-integral-use-a-power-series?rq=1)

Comment: You are asking to interchange integration and sum of the series. There are limit theorems that let you to this. (monotone convergence, dominated convergence, Fubini's theorem,others?) But you have to check the conditions for the theorem to be applied.  Unfortunately, those conditions are not satisfied here.

Comment: @GEdgar Ok I don't want to sound ignorant, but if the power series represents the function, and if one integrated that it would be possible, but not for this example right? My thought is one can not imply that integration power series statement equals the original integration, because the power series represents the function?

Comment: You are right. The two lines in the OP are equivalent.  What is not correct is $$\sum_\limits{k=0}^\infty\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k(x^{2k})}{k!}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}2$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you exchange the integral and the series blindly, the integral of each term is infinite, showing that it was not allowable to exchange the series and the integral.

Remember that $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx$ means 
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_0^N e^{-x^2}\,dx.
$$
Now you can do (as you saw in the post you mention, because the convergence of the series is uniform on closed intervals)
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_0^N\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k x^{2k}}{k!}\,dx
=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_0^N\frac{(-1)^k x^{2k}}{k!}\,dx
=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k N^{2k+1}}{k!(2k+1)}.
$$
And now you need to calculate the new series. The best method is to notice that it is the anti-derivative of $e^{-x^2}$ at $x=N$, so 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k N^{2k+1}}{k!(2k+1)}=\int_0^Ne^{-x^2}\,dx. 
$$
Not super useful.

Comment: +1. Letting $N\to \infty$ in the LHS of the last line  is surely one of the worst ways to numerically calculate $\sqrt \pi\,/2.$